# How to find in mongoose with deep population?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I succeed to make a deep population with find and the search key in first model, but now i want to find by key on the sub object generated by the deep populate.

I have three models : Product, Category, and Event

I want to find my Products by **e_fk_club_id** that is in **Event** model

I tried two solutions but they didn't work

First solution in find :

```
model.find({'categories.events.e_fk_club_id':id})`
```

Second solution with match :

```
 `$match : { e_fk_club_id : id }`
```

these are my models

**product.js**

```
 var ProductSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

        p_id: Number,
        p_name: String,
        p_fk_category: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'categories'},

    }
    ,  {collection: 'products'});


module.exports = mongoose.model('products', ProductSchema);
```

**Category.js**

```
 var CategorySchema = new mongoose.Schema({

            c_id: Number,
            c_name: String,
            c_fk_event: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'events'},

        }
        ,  {collection: 'categories'});


    module.exports = mongoose.model('categories', CategorySchema);
```

**Event.js**

```
 var EventSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

            e_id: Number,
            e_name: String,
            e_fk_club_id: Number,

        }
        ,  {collection: 'events'});


    module.exports = mongoose.model('events', EventSchema);
```

This is the code which i am trying to fetch the data :

```
getProductsByClub:function (id, callback){
            var model = require("Product");


            //model
            model .find({'categories.events.e_fk_club_id':id})

            .populate({
                path:'p_fk_category',
                model:'categories',
                populate:
                    {
                    path:'e_fk_event',
                        model:'events',
                        //$match : { e_fk_club_id : id }
                }
            })




                .exec (function(err, doc){
                    if (err) {

                        callback(err) ;

                    } else {
                        callback(doc) ;

                    }
                })
        },
```

Is There any solution.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: i cant find `e_tarif` or `e_collectes` or `c_fk_club_id` in your schema, can you write the schema properly

Comment: Sorry, I have updated to the correct models

Comment: can you tell me which `id` is this : `model .find({'categories.events.e_fk_club_id':id})` ?

Comment: Can you tell clearly what you are trying to achieve, its not clear from your question, its kind of confusing.

Comment: I want to find products by the e_fk_club_id wich is on sub of the sub object
(evenet is the sub object of the category and category is the sub object of product)

Comment: It is not sub object but a `reference`. In reference you can't query like the way you are doing. Until and unless it is `populated`, you cant refer the `fields` of `referenced document`.

Comment: Are you so focused on using different schema and Population? I can help you achieve what you want, using `embedded documents`, if you want. Without using `mongoose.populate`

Comment: No, you can give me solution with embedded documents, thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130718/discussion-between-ravi-shankar-and-user2285831).

Comment: Do you need to have different collection for event, product and companies?